# Delete directory content using WinSCP

Tags: winscp

Is there a way to delete directory content using WinSCP?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
synchronize remote -delete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete a directory, use the [`rm` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_rm).

The `synchronize ... -delete` deletes only orphan files or directories.

See also [How do I create script that synchronizes files and deletes synchronized files from source afterward?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_delete_synchronized_files)